# VirtualBox Errors when starting whonix

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to download whonix on my computer but I get 2 errors:

First Error: "The memory could not be written",

Second Error: "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine"
and then it says aborted.

[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V92E3.png)

[SecondError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fspPy.png)

I have no idea what to do, I tried to:

1. Reinstall VirtualBox
2. Write in cmd: "sfc /scannow"
3. Install oldest versions of VirtualBox
4. Write custom size in virtual Memory(Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced system settings->(Performance)settings->Advanced->Change->Custom size)
5. Updates VirtualBox+Windows+Whonix+Drives
6. Enabled Intel Virtualization Technology(in BIOS->CPU Configuration)
7. Deactivate the 3d acceleration but I have no idea how

and nothing works :(

If it helps I have:

Operating system: Windows 10 Pro

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz   3.20 GHz

Graphics Card: GTX 1080

Installed RAM: 32.0 GB

System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Hope someone could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem
solution: VirtualBox → Settings → Storage → Type: AHCI → OK
it worked for me

Comment: If you can see this message so THANK YOU!!!